# Suggested edit reviewers can unilaterally approve or reject unlimited edits per day

Tags: bug, status-review, review, edits, suggested-edits

When a user completes a review item, a POST request is made to `/review/task-reviewed/<review-id>` supplying (among others) the reviewer's choice (`taskResultTypeId`).

In the Suggested Edits queue, however, if the user chooses "Edit" or "Reject and Edit" *before the review is submitted*, an additional POST request is made to `/posts/<post-id>/edit-submit/<....>` in order to apply the reviewer's changes to the post.

This is flawed:

- I can manually make a request to send a ["Reject and Edit"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33811997) or an ["Edit"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33805538) review. The task will be shown as completed, but it may [re-enter the queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33807187) (if it's possible, that is).
- I can manually send a request to edit a post forcing Community to [approve](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33809554) or [reject](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33776170) the proposed edit without leaving a review myself.

Comment: Just noting, this bug doesn't necessarily have to be performed by directly/manually sending requests to specific end points. If the tab is refreshed, closed, or connectivity is lost between clicking "Save edits" and the review being submitted you get the same effect. This is likely the way that most users would experience this.